# Visual Studio .Net Developer : How do I structure an android studio project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-studio, xamarin

I am now starting to learn android development.

I made a small app in visual studio using xamarin (C#) and I wanted copy it to android studio so I can also learn a new language and a new IDE.

I currently have a solution (App.sln) under that I have the main project (App.csproj) and also a class library project to hold my classes (App.Model.csproj)

In android studio, do I create a new module and call it com.app.model or do I just create a new package in the main module?

Comment: This question is a little too broad. You should probably follow some beginner Android Studio tutorials([such as this one](http://www.androidauthority.com/android-studio-tutorial-beginners-637572/)) to understand the general project structure and basic concepts, and then try to copy your C# application logic over piece by piece. Usually it is more work than it is worth to simply "copy over" an existing project into a new environment, since best-practices in the original framework might be inefficient or inappropriate in a different framework.

Comment: I'm not an Android developer (yet!) but after some basic searching for "migrate c# to android" I found [this forum topic](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4759/migrate-c-winforms-code-to-android) which reiterates the fact that it's probably not worth attempting a direct migration due to performance concerns and UI compatibility.

Comment: the app is no longer than 100 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using Xamarin Native approach, the porting from C# to Android Java should be quite straight forward because most of the API is still the same name. The difference mostly is just TitleCase in C# but camelCase in Java. Also, you will need to rename Android layout file from *.axml to *.xml.

If you are using Xamarin.Forms approach, then you will not able to port to Java easily because the API is totally different compare to native Android now. Xamarin.Forms is having its own API set that mapped back to individual native platform's API.

Checking out native Android tutorial will help you to understand better. However, why you want to go back to native when you already know about Xamarin. I came from Android native background and I didn't look back into native since I started with Xamarin.